# reverse string program is not working correctly

Tags: c++, string

I tried writing a string reversing program in C++. Though it seemed really simple, Idk why I ain't getting the correct output.
**Here's my code:-**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

string Reverse_string( string &s ){
    for( size_t i{}; i<s.size() ; i++ ){
        s.at(i)= s.at( s.size()-1-i );
    }
    return s;
}
int main(){
    cout<<"Enter the string you want to reverse: ";
    string s{};
    getline(cin,s);
    cout<<"\nThe reversed string is :"<< Reverse_string(s) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Here is my output:-**
Enter the string you want to reverse: string

The reversed string is :gniing

Please help me finding the bug!

Comment: you're swapping wrongly, correct swapping statements: t=a; a=b; b=t

Comment: and swap to size()/2 only, or all values are swapped back to original indices

Comment: code fixed here: https://repl.it/@datdinhquoc/InternalTrueTrial#main.cpp

Comment: You might think about why you're passing a reference and modifying the original string as well as returning a new string.

Comment: You logic is wrong.   Assuming the input is `"string"`, the first iteration of the loop (with `i = 0`) produces `"gtring"`.   The only inputs to the second iteration are `i` (value `1`) and the string `"gtring"`.   Since the string now contains no characters equal to `'s'`, there is no way that the loop can ever cause any character to be `'s'`.    But the reversed string that *should* be produced is `"gnirts"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are assigning the values `s.at(i)= s.at( s.size()-1-i );` and thus it is changing the previous value of `s.at(i)`, but you should swap the values of respective indexes, `s.at(i)` with `s.at(s.size()-1-i)`. And also you only need to traverse the first half of the string to swap with respective last half of the string.

This works fine.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

string Reverse_string( string &s ){
    for( size_t i{}; i<s.size()/2 ; i++ ){  // here you only need to go half
        swap(s.at(i), s.at( s.size()-1-i ));  // swap is builtin function
    }
    return s;
}
int main(){
    cout<<"Enter the string you want to reverse: ";
    string s{};
    getline(cin,s);
    cout<<"\nThe reversed string is :"<< Reverse_string(s) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just missed the point that I am changing the previous values and so, wouldn't be able to assign the right values in the 2nd half part of the string!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using functions. You can just use the headerfile `#include <algorithm>`. There is a built in `reverse` function.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cout << "Enter the string you want to reverse: ";
    std::cin >> s;
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    std::cout << "The reversed string is: " << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it is not for his/her expectation. Maybe just learning how to use algorithms very well.

Comment: No reason not to make the suggestion. If the current asker can't make use of this approach, perhaps the next one can. This asker won't be the last and is far from the first. This question gets asked and answered every week or two.

Comment: @user4581301 - Yeah, I was kind of  torn between answering this question or not because it looks like it could be a possible dup. I can delete it if you think I should. Glad to see you're making it through the pandemic!

Comment: Leave it. Causes no harm.